# Quill Editor Color Based On Validator

Tags: css, angular, ngx-quill

Quill Editor with validation

```
<quill-editor formControlName="qed" placeholder="Input notes, minimum 10 char" [minLength]="10" required></quill-editor>

.ng-invalid {border: 2px solid red}
```

Once validation fails will have a red border triggered by `ng-invalid`, corresponding element is `<div class="ql-editor">`

[image]

It doesn't happens. F12 finds out because `ng-invalid` shows up in its grandparent `<quill-editor>`:

```
<quill-editor formcontrolname="qed" class="ng-invalid">
  <div class="ql-toolbar ql-snow">...</div>
  <div quill-editor-element>
    <div class="ql-editor">Red Here!</div>
  </div>
</quill-editor>
```

Can't figure out how to make it without code unless to check its grandparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries, place inside **top/root level `styles.css`**:

```
.ng-invalid .ql-editor {border: 2px solid red}
.ng-valid .ql-editor {border: 2px solid green}
```